# How to get value from one page to another page using input name jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

I want to get the textbox value from one page to another page using input name in jquery.

```
$('input[name$="testName"]').val("@Model.Value")
```

above this code is not working in another page, please anyone help me.

Comment: Pass it in the session, querystring, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass value in query string or somehow you cannot access directly.

Comment: please, am new to jquery how to pass value query string.

Comment: window.location.htef="index.php?foo="+bar;

Comment: chandresh, how to store the input name from another page to the session

Comment: simple $_SESSION['textfieldval'] = $_POST['val'] or $_GET['val'];

Comment: boss, $_SESSION is undefined what can i do

Answer (score 0):

You could save it to an param or save it to an hidden field. But you cant access it directly.

Comment: hi, how to save it as a param